# What is this WaitForTransform and lookupTransform function overloading do?

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually I use method of both tf function that only accept `source_frame` and `target_frame`. Recently I discover from amcl source code that there is another function overloading that accepts more argumentd like `fixed_frame`, `source_time`, `target_time`. I have read the documentation and still don't understand what is these function and its argument do.

Even more the code from amcl sets `target_frame` and `source_frame` value with same frame that is `base_frame_id`, why?

```
  // wait a little for the latest tf to become available
  tf_->waitForTransform(base_frame_id_, msg.header.stamp,
                       base_frame_id_, now,
                       odom_frame_id_, ros::Duration(0.5));
  tf_->lookupTransform(base_frame_id_, msg.header.stamp,
                       base_frame_id_, now,
                       odom_frame_id_, tx_odom);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298877/what-is-this-waitfortransform-and-lookuptransform-function-overloading-do?/) by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can read about it in the "Time Travel tutorials" [c++](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf2%20%28C%2B%2B%29), [python](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Time%20travel%20with%20tf2%20%28Python%29)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1